# Does Google return search results based on words that are found only in the site's domain name?

Tags: seo, domains, google-search, keywords

I want to create a website called `forname-lastname.com` and publish various articles on this website. These articles should be indexed commonly by the keywords on the article pages.
However, when you search for "forname lastname" will the site be in the index at all? Assumption: "forname lastname" occurs nowhere on the page, except the domain name.
I am asking because I don't want "forname lastname" leading to that domain, even though the domain  name matches. So the question is whether a domain name can be a reason to appear in Search results.

Answer (score 2):

Google is going to try to answer the user's query.  What your asking is for Google to intentionally not answer the users' questions.  If your name is the name of the domain, and your site's name best matches the intent of the user's query, not having Google display your site is counter intuitive to the search engine's purpose.

To complicate matters, will your articles all be anonymous?  What about your "About Us/Me" page?  Will it be anonymous too?  Even if search engines ignore your domain name, you will show up somewhere in the search results as the author of your pages.  A ranking factor is the trustworthiness and authority of the author.

Lastly, I suspect that Google would interpret your intent (based solely on your question) as questionable content and possibly not index your entire site.  Any kind of manipulation to hide your identity, even if completely well intentioned, would seem like an untrustworthy site.

I'd suggest googling search engine EAT principle - Expertise Authority and Trustworthiness, and see if you can still provide EAT while attempting to do what you need to do with your website.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible, but i'm no marketing expert cause you can have noindex nofollow etc on the main homepage maybe, and setup the articles on a different page which might work, I think the issue you're going to have is the fact what you mentioned here "I don't want "forname lastname" leading to that domain, eventhough the domain name matches. ". If people are searching these articles, it will come back to your website, and the more views/interactions they get, the more your link gets pushed up.

All I could suggest is to change  tag and literally focus all your H1,2,3 etc else where, I don't think you can hide firstname lastname if your website got so popular just from the articles linking to it. I don't quite understand why you would want to hide it anyway.

Comment: The reason: Want to set up a blog with a domain name as my name. But don't want people to find it if they google my name. But if they google topics I am writing about they should find it.

Comment: right i see, try doing what I suggested in meantime with the noindex nofollow etc on the main homepage etc, but I'm not quite sure until someone with more marketing knowledge answers